# Is it possible to build something similar to a CMD prompt in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cmd

I'm 100% brand new to Ruby, still learning on Code Academy. I was wondering if it's possible (without learning something different) to build something that looks similar to the Windows Command Prompt, but it doesn't actually *do* anything except allow you to type commands.

I guess it would be more like a CMD prompt simulator?

Comment: Are you wondering if you can create a window that acts like a command prompt, or create a program that runs in a console that acts like a command prompt?

Comment: `loop{print "Enter command: "; gets}`?

Comment: It's possible, and Rails won't be needed to do it. Using  `puts %x(#{gets.chomp})` will get you started but there's a lot more to it because you need to support the features of cmd.

Comment: loop{ puts '>'; eval(gets) } this will allow you to continuously enter and run ruby code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so lets start by saying Ruby doesn't provide a `GUI` framework. You'll be dropping down into a `C` framework (using *bindings* of course) and then from there you could create a `GUI` type text-only program.

If you're looking for just a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) that hijacks a `cmd` window then a *super simple** solution from the question comments would work. If you want something more then take a look at **irb** (in Ruby's `stdlib`) or [**pry**](http://pryrepl.org/).

** Succinct is the qualifier for "simple" in this case. Someone new wouldn't be expected to understand what's going on.*

Comment: From the description on the link, a REPL is exactly what I'm looking for, and you've answered my question. Thank you!